# Apresentar uma soma online

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde!
Tenho um formulário e uma rotina em JAVASCRIPT.
O meu desejo é que, a partir de uma digitação, apareça automaticamente o valor da soma.
Um exemplo que busco é o site da [YOUSE](https://www.youse.com.br/home/order/32c3b370-5c2e-4d47-a73d-4cd1fe183eb3/coverages_selection), em que alterando o valor das coberturas do seguro, automaticamente o custo é apresentado (sem "TAB", "BOTÕES").

No meu exemplo, quando você altera, só com o TAB em N2 que atualiza. Outro ponto, que apesar de estar "pré preenchido", não é disponibilizado por exemplo a soma de N1 e N2 (no caso - 50).

FORMULÁRIO:

```
<input type="number" id="n1" value="20">
<input type="number" id="n2" value="30" onblur="calcularonline()"> 
<input type="text" id="n3" value="100">
<input name="idade" type="number" placeholder=0 id="id_idade">
<div id="resultado"</div>
<div id="resultado2"</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function calcularonline() {
  var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n1').value, 10);
  var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n2').value, 10);
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = n1 + n2;

  var n3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('n3').value, 10);
  var n4 = (parseInt(document.getElementById('id_idade').value, 10))*2;
  var n5 = 0;

  if(n4>=10){
      n5 = 10000;
  }
  document.getElementById('resultado2').innerHTML = n3 + n4 + n5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, veja se é isso de que precisa:

```js
function Somar() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

    if (num1 == '') {
        num1 = 0;
    }

    if (num2 == '') {
        num2 = 0;
    }

    var resultado = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);    
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = resultado;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Exemplo</title>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Escreva algum número para ativar a função.</p>
    <input type="text" id="num1" oninput="Somar()">
    <input type="text" id="num2" oninput="Somar()">
    <p id="resultado"></p>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show. Willian, obrigado pela atenção!!